Appropriate test for difference in microbial abundance between forest types
I want to test the difference between microbial abundance between two forest types at 10 cm and 50 cm ( independent at this point). The first plot (10 cm) the does not meet normality so I use a non parametric test, the other (50 cm) does  meet normality so i use a T test. Is this appropriate or should they be the same test regardless? Thank you for any advice.



It is not the marginal distributions which need to be normal which is a condition to run a t-test. It is the sampling distribution of the difference of means which needs to be normal. Now, we have only 1 instance of that random variable, so we can not really test it. Yes, if the marginal distributions are normal, that is a sufficient conditions, but it is not a necessary condition.
What test did you use for checking normality? How did the Q-Q plots look like? How bad was departure from normality? Depending on how severe the departure from normality is, the lack of normality could be a minor problem, and your results would still be valid. Particularly so if your sample sizes (btw, what are they?) are sufficiently large, because the CLT comes to the rescue. "Tradition" says >30; but it could be less than that (low unimodal skewness, etc.) or more (large skewness). Your sample sizes seem to be in the 15-ish per group? Which seems to be a bit low to safely argue CLT, but also a bit low to trust a normality test...
What non-parametric test did you run? From what I can guess you used a Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt), aka Wilcoxon Mann Whitney. The issue is that the MWUt and the t-test (you seem to have used the Welch variant; good) test 2 completely different null hypotheses. MWUt tests for stochastic superiority ($P(X>Y)=P(X<Y); the probability that a random value from the first sample is greater than a random value from the 2nd sample, is equal to the probability that a random value from the first sample is lower than a random value from the 2nd sample; aka stochastic equality). Welch t-test tests for equality of means. You can easily find distributions where X is stochastically superior to Y, but the mean of X is lower than the mean of Y. So running 1 test for 1 depth, and another for another depth makes very little sense.

Honestly, I would run both, for both depths, so a total of 4 tests. Now, some will undoubtly comment that this is a form of p-hacking. I do not share this view; this is data exploration; what is the data telling us? You can certainly (probably should) use a multiple comparison correction (MCC) to account for the fact that, with 4 tests, you increase your chances of a false positive (Bonferroni, Sidak, ...). Based on your graphs, even with MCC, the MWUt will still be significant at the first depth, and the t-test will not be at the 2nd depth. Also, the t-test at the first depth will almost certainly be significant, and so will the MWUt at the 2nd depth. And actually, with both tests at both depths, testing different nulls, you are likely to have a more interesting story to tell.
Now, if you already had a hypothesis before analyzing the data (e.g. there is a difference between forests, at both depths), which you are trying to prove, then this is no longer exploratory analysis. Then you should stick with only 1 test, and it probably should be MWUt, because the use of a t-test at the first depth is subject to challenge.
Note also that there are other options for your tests, such as bootstraping; this would allow you to test for equality of means regardless of normality. But if your sample sizes are only ~15, it is challenging to expect it to be representative enough for bootstrap...

The sample size for each depth and forest is 18. So if i stick to one test ideally it should be the non parametric test because some of the data is not normal?

If exploratory, I would definitively use both tests, to see what they say... (and not worry too much about normality; btw, it would help if you update the question with Q-Q plots). If confirmatory, I would use whichever test was used in the preliminary studies, and gave you an indication of possible significance. If you absolutely need 1 and only 1 test, then yes, the non-parametric, because it does not raise questions from your audience/reviewers about normality.
